# How does powershell handle transitive / nested module imports?

Tags: powershell, module

I always thought that doing `Import-Module` in my current powershell console will make the module available throughout the console.

Recently however I have learned that when doing `Import-Module` from within a module, things are getting complicated.

Compare:

> ## [Windows PowerShell Session State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714451%28v=vs.85%29.aspx=)
>
> ...
>
> ### Module Session State
>
> Module session states are created whenever the module or one of its nested modules is imported into the session. When a module exports an element such as a cmdlet, function, or script, a reference to that element is added to the global session state of the session. However, when the element is run, it is executed within the session state of the module.

What I can observe, is:

```
# This is mod1.psm1
Import-Module -Force mod2.psm1
# end mod1.psm1
```

-

```
PS> Import-Module -Force mod1.psm1
```

... This will make the functions of mod**2**.psm1 available *via* mod1, when checked with `Get-Module`

```
PS> Import-Module -Force mod2.psm1
```

... This will make the functions of mod2 available via mod2.

I don't even fully understand the behavior here, but now comes the interesting part:

```
# This is mod1.psm1
function fn_load_in_mod1 {
  Import-Module -Force mod2.psm1

  # mod2 stuff can be used here
}
# end mod1.psm1

PS> Import-Module -Force mod1.psm1
PS> # But here, no mod2 stuff is available anymore!
```

I learned that to make the mod2 stuff available to my console, I need to:

```
# This is mod1.psm1
function fn_load_in_mod1 {
  Import-Module -Force mod2.psm1 -Global

  # mod2 stuff can be used here, and with the -Global switch also "outside"
}
# end mod1.psm1
```

But I can't make head nor tail of that session state stuff.

How am I supposed to do an `Import-Module` from *within* a module "correctly"?

Comment: As far as I see we need to call the module1 first after importing then only we can access module2 globally. If we directly call module2 function with out module1 it is throwing error